Building a bootable DOS CD or USB flash drive
I have several DOS based utilities that I use in Ham Radio to work on old VHF radios. I built an SSD that boots from DOS and copied the utilities to that SSD and that works in the shack.
What I want to do is image that disk and either burn it to a CD or burn it to a USB flash drive. I purchased WinISO but I have not been able to make the image bootable. I'm missing something.
If I point to the original 6.22 ISO, downloaded from “All Boot Disks,” for the boot image all I on the CD is that image. None of the other files are added. If I point to my SSD all I get is the files no boot.
BTW, Rufus does not like the ISO I downloaded or any of the ISO's I have made. But it seems to be the choice for bootable USB flash drive creation.
09/28/2024
Searching through the posts I found this one ...
How do I create a custom, bootable MS-DOS ISO image?
Sounds very much like what I wanted to so I followed the instructions and it did not work.  The ISO was recognized by my burner software, WinISO, but the disks cannot be read.  They show a burned area, they are not blank, but they do not boot.  Neither does Windows Explorer find a file on the disk so I guess you could say they are magically blank.  But you can't write anything more to them.  On a side note I use Windows 10 and usually I just right click on the ISO file, tell it to burn it and it works.  Doesn't work with these ISO files.
Any other ideas?  I will continue to work on it.

Does it need to be MS-DOS or would the programs also work on FreeDOS?

The app will run in FreeDOS or DOSBox but it wants direct access to the serial port, COM1 or COM2.  So for my purposes it will not work.

You should be able to use free Rufus to make a bootable DOS USB: https://support.onlogic.com/documentation/dosusb/ . That said, my preference would be to make a virtual machine, such as VirtualBox, that runs DOS -- it has the advantage of not needing to reboot the PC to use a few utilities. When I needed 32-bit tools to run on a 64-bit PC, it worked well, and was faster than I would have expected.

I'm not talking about DOSBox. Where did that even come from? I was asking about FreeDOS as in an operating system, not as in an emulator.

Rufus first.  I have Rufus and use it to see if the ISO file I created is viable.  So far none of my home made ISO files are viable.  Perhaps I should build an image file?

I mentioned DOSbox because it was one of two DOS options I tested initially.  The second I tried was FreeDOS.  Both of these options failed because the utility is very old, like the radio it services, and it expects a direct access to COM1.  Even using the COM setting in FreeDOS would not work.  The utility ran but could not access the radio via the Com port.
